# Automatically open Snip & Sketch editor after using snipping tool with Win+Shift+S

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool

The new version of the snipping tool in Windows 10 has some nice features, but one big difference between its behavior and that of the old snipping tool is that you can either use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command to go directly into snipping mode, which then places the image into the clipboard, or you can open the "Snip & Sketch" from which you must click "new" but the resulting snip will be open in the editor once taken.

In the old tool, you could open it in snipping mode, and then it would open the editor directly once you snip the screen. From there you can annotate and save the file, or copy it to the clipboard.

The new tool does (sometimes) pop up a notification you can click to open the editor, but I have had instances where the notification did not appear, or got lost in a torrent of notifications.

Is there a way to change the behavior such that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will invoke snipping mode, and the editor will open automatically to allow annotation, cropping, and saving?

Alternatively, a way to open the app directly into "new" mode, or to at the very least save a copy of the snip to some folder so it can be found later? Not every application allows pasting of images, sometimes you need to "Open" them. Or you may want to both paste it and save it.

So far, I haven't been able to find a way to emulate the simplicity of the old workflow - other than simply using the old snipping tool.

Comment: Not an answer, but as a workaround for this I just use Greenshot and the "print screen" button. You can easily set Greenshot to open in the editor after capture. The editing tools in GS are far superior as well IMHO.

Comment: I figured out why this happens. Check your Windows Notification Settings. If it is set to Alarm only, the Snip tool pop up does not show up.

Answer (score 11):

You can open the Snip & Sketch app directly in "new" mode by right-clicking the app (on either the Start Menu App List, on the pinned tile, or on the Task Bar) and select "Take a new snip" from the Jump List menu.

The Clipboard History feature (October 2018 update) will save and list all items sent to the clipboard, including any snips. These items can then be accessed through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The hotkey will also take you to the setup for Clipboard History if the feature is not enabled.

As for your other concerns, I am not sure of how to open editor automatically after sniping using the hotkeys. But the following information could be of use.

If you take a snip using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, the Snip & Sketch App's notification should be accessible at the top of the Action/Notification Center side bar even if there's no pop-up. The Notification Center can be accessed through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or through the Notification icon at the end of the task bar ([Windows Tips](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/tips/home/get-notifications#findnotifications)). Clicking on the Snip & Sketch's notification there will launch the editor with the latest snip.

You could thus use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for a snip, then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and click on the notification to launch editing.

Comment: I don't get anything in notification center when using shift-win-s. In fact I don't see the snip & sketch app at all in the start menu

Answer (score 6):

I had a fresh Windows 10 installation, and the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **was working, but it did not give any notification** (and possibility to edit the snip).

The problem was solved by installing the Snip & Sketch ***from the Windows Store***.

After installation, after every snip, I started getting the following notification, and clicking it gave the possibility to edit the image.

[image: after installation]

---

It is also possible to disable the "Snip & Sketch" notifications in the notification settings (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Manage notifications) so make sure you have not disabled them.

Comment: For me I'd disabled the notification

Comment: This is the true answer, thanks!

Comment: In my case, the organization has disabled all notifications via Group Policy.  So, nothing can be done to make it work as expected.  Now I'm sad.

Comment: Could it be nowadays called Snipping Tool?

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotKey script I made for this:

```
printscreen::

mousepressed=0

Run, explorer ms-screenclip:

sleep, 1000

Loop
{

sleep, 10
if (GetKeyState("LButton","P")=1)
mousepressed=1
else
if mousepressed=1
{
sleep, 1000
send #a
sleep, 500
send {tab}
sleep, 500
send {tab}
sleep, 500
send {down}
sleep, 500
send {enter}
break
}
}


Return
```

This script binds printscreen key to launch Snip & Sketch, then wait for the mouse to be pressed, then to be released, then goes to notification center, chooses the notification from Snip & Sketch and opens it - there you can edit and save your snip.

But this won't help if, like you've said, the notification won't appear for some reason or another notification comes after it - because the script relies on choosing the first notification from the list.
But basically it should work and save you a ton of time.